# Contraction of the union of $m+3$ $m$-dimensional convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: general-topology

How can I prove that the union of $m+3$ $m$-dimensional convex sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the intersection of every $m+2$ sets is not empty is contractible?

Answer (score 1):

If the intersection of all $m+3$ sets is nonempty then the union is star shaped, so contractible.

Suppose to the contrary that the intersection is trivial, let S be the m+3rd set. For $1\leq i \leq m+2$ let $s_i$ be a point which is in all the subsets except subset i. In particular, each $s_i$ is in S, which is $m$ dimensional and convex. So any point in the convex hull of the $s_i$ is contained in the convex hull of at most $m+1$ of them by Caratheodory's theorem. But any element in the convex hull of at most $m+1$ of these points is contained in all $m+3$ convex subsets we started with. This is a contradiction.

Comment: There's still a gap in this I think, but it may be useful so I'll leave it up.